# Long lines of code getting shortened in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have no idea what hot-key I pressed, I am getting this:

[image]

It is supposed to write that whole code into a line.

Comment: Are you using Resharper?

Comment: No, I am using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: It behaves like some sort of padding, it has affected my whole solution and I cannot see anything properly.

Comment: Delete at the end of each line doesn't put the whole code in the same line?

Comment: How are you dead? The code will still work. go to Tools|Options|Text Editor|All Languages and uncheck word wrap.

Comment: Or Edit/Advanced/Word Wrap (shortcut is CTRL+E+W)

Comment: Don`t be silly, you're not dead. Vampires and zombies are dead. All you are afflicted with is a manager with an unusual fetish for impractical (and non-significant) code formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordwrap it from `Tools > Options...>Text Editor>`. If for all languages go to `All Languages` or for a particular one to that specific language.

Shortcut -> Ctrl + E + W

[image]

**OR**

You can do `Edit > Advanced > WordWrap`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, 10 minutes and I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#

Uncheck `Word wrap`

Answer (score 1):

```
Edit -> Advanced -> Word wrap
```

Or

```
CTRL+E,W
```